# Most efficient way to manipulate DOM before first page display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm building a single-page app (HTML5, JS, JQuery, Bootstrap) and need to swap various UI elements, from the default layout defined in my HTML around (divs with quite a few children), in response to user prefs (loaded from localstorage during JS load).

Currently in `$(document).ready()` I'm using `$(somediv).append()` or `.prepend()` to move these elements around. The problem is that visually the user sees the browser render the default layout as defined by the HTML, then the new layout gets rendered. I'd like to a) make this whole process more efficient and b) not display the UI to the user until it's in the final re-arranged state.

Possible solutions I could think of are:

1. Define `<body>` as `visibility:hidden` in HTML then change it to `visible` once DOM manipulation is done using `$(document).ready()`
2. Same as 1. but using `display:none` and `display:block` instead of `visibility`
3. (possibly with 1 or 2) `$().detach()` everything inside the body once DOM ready, do my manipulation, then insert into `<body>`
4. leave the `<body>` empty, have the body contents in a JS string which I then load into a JQuery fragment, re-arrange the elements as needed and then insert them into the body. This doesn't seem like a good option as it stops me from easily editing and previewing the HTML.

I want to reduce the work for the browser as much as possible, and display the final result to the user as quickly as possible. Ideally I want to tell the browser not to do any initial HTML rendering until DOM is manipulated, but I don't think this is possible?

Also, this needs to work on a wide variety of browsers across desktop/tablet/phone.

Comment: There are no significant performance differences between methods mentioned and re-ordering the dom is not a problem cross browser either. Beyond that it simply becomes an opinion on which approach to take. Pick one and try it

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding changing the `visibility` or the `display` would be the most efficient way.

This way the browser only needs to perform a few things with JS and for the most part (if your js doesn't take too long) users wont see a blank page for too long.

You could also display a "loading" message to tell your visitors that the site will be displayed in a while and that it does work.